# android rotate animation quality

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a rotation animation which I am applying it to a view, here is the code:

```
    RotateAnimation shake = new RotateAnimation(-3, 3, 10, 10);
    shake.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    shake.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    shake.setDuration(SHAKE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
```

But while playing animation, my view's margins get pixelated:

[image: image:]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you load your image, set the Anti-alias flag.
In XML:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tile" 
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:antialias="true"/>
```

On the fly:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: Could this help fix this issue too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837600/how-to-avoid-pixelation-when-resizing-shrinking-images-on-android