# RotateAnimation on RelativeLayout image quality

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have a problem with the **RotateAnimation** on older devices. My images get very pixelated, pretty much like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432169/android-rotate-animation-quality), but for the whole image (and its background), not only the margins.

I do not rotate the `ImageView` itself but on a `RelativeLayout` which contains two images and a `ProgressBar`. In addition the `ImageView` has a 9-patch as a background.

As I load the images dynamically I guess I cannot set the antialiasing flag in the `XML`. So I tried to do this:

```
((BitmapDrawable) myImageView.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true);
```

This does not seem to have any effect. On newer devices like the `Galaxy Nexus` the images do not get pixelated at all, so my guess is that it might have something to do with hardware accelleration.

Any idea on how I can get a smooth rotation without this pixelating?