# How to avoid pixelation when resizing (shrinking) images on Android?

Tags: android, image-processing

We are resizing photos taken with the camera down to about 1024x768 for uploading.  On most Android devices, our code works ok, but on some they don't (such as Motorola Photon 4G, Galaxy Nexus, Motorola Droid X2).

We're using the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234895/679339

But when it doesn't work, the resized image looks like this: [image: pixalated]

Anybody know why?

Comment: JPEG artefacts? What if you set quality to 100?

Comment: Hi Roger, would you mind explaining a bit more about what you mean?  Am fairly new to this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android resizes images based on the pixel density of the device its running on.  You need to get the display size and density of the device in order to understand what Android will attempt to do to your photo based on the View its trying to put the image into

Comment: Thanks.  So Galaxy Nexus is apparently the only device that has this problem now.  Once we get the display size and density, what should I do with it?

Comment: +no, it's not just Google Nexus.  It's any time you take an image and manipulate its size using JPEG.  It's a lossy compression. Change the size enough (and the Nexus has a nice, big camera relative to 1024x768) and you'll lose enough information  make it look bad.