# Surface of line is not exactly smooth When the line is not been drawn at ninety degree angle

Tags: android

I am using a tilt effect which rotates an image to certain angle, but when the image is rotated, the straight line becomes a bit uneven (the surface of the line is not smooth).

Here is the image of it: [image]

How can I remove this? I don't think it is the problem with code. I am  guessing that it has something to do with the GPU or something like that.

Here is the code:

```
public class TiltAnimation extends Animation {

    private static final String TAG = "com.fourmob.tilteffect.TiltAnimation";

    public static final int ROTATE_AXIS_X = 0;
    public static final int ROTATE_AXIS_Y = 1;

    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;

    private Camera mCamera;

    private final ArrayList<Rotation> mRotations = new ArrayList<Rotation>();

    public TiltAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float centerX, float centerY, int rotateAxe) {
        this(centerX, centerY);
        mRotations.add(new Rotation(rotateAxe, fromDegrees, toDegrees));
    }

    public TiltAnimation(float centerX, float centerY) {
        mCenterX = centerX;
        mCenterY = centerY;
    }

    public void addRotation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, int rotateAxe) {
        mRotations.add(new Rotation(rotateAxe, fromDegrees, toDegrees));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final float centerX = mCenterX;
        final float centerY = mCenterY;

        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        mCamera.save();

        for(Rotation rotation : mRotations) {
            Log.d(TAG, "rotation : " + rotation);
            float degrees = rotation.mFromDegrees + ((rotation.mToDegrees - rotation.mFromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);
            if(rotation.mRotateAxis == ROTATE_AXIS_X) {
                mCamera.rotateX(degrees);
            } else if(rotation.mRotateAxis == ROTATE_AXIS_Y) {
                mCamera.rotateY(degrees);
            }
        }

        mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
        mCamera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    }

    public void addRotations(Rotation... rotations) {
        mRotations.addAll(Arrays.asList(rotations));
    }


    public static final class Rotation {
        int mRotateAxis;
        float mFromDegrees;
        float mToDegrees;

        public Rotation(int mAxis, float mFromDegrees, float mToDegrees) {
            this.mRotateAxis = mAxis;
            this.mFromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
            this.mToDegrees = mToDegrees;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Rotation{" +
                    "mRotateAxis=" + (mRotateAxis == ROTATE_AXIS_X ? "X":"Y") +
                    ", mFromDegrees=" + mFromDegrees +
                    ", mToDegrees=" + mToDegrees +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give valid reasons for downvotes.....Tell me what you didn't understand ?

Comment: Do i need to disable aliasing or enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Since aliasing is your ENEMY, you have to get rid of it:
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432169/android-rotate-animation-quality).
Very easy.