# ImageView setRotation having an aliased or jagged edges

Tags: android

Hi currently I'm trying to display an image that is rotated by about 5 degrees on an imageview after I capture it and rotate the image into proper orientation (camera issues). Now the problem is after setting the image on an imageview which is rotated 5 degrees sing `imageview.setRotation(5)` the imageview itself becomes aliased. I'm pretty sure that the imageview is the one being aliased since my image has a padding of 5dp to have a white border on the sides but please do correct me if I'm wrong.

What solution I tried so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378573/bitmap-not-drawn-anti-aliased/14459129) but the sample solution works for already set image on a custom view and I'm not that used to in configuring or further customizing a custom views to work based on what I need. though his problem is almost the same as mine.

I also tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432169/android-rotate-animation-quality) which apply antialiasing on the fly but didn't work as well.

So far here is my code:

```
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_preview);
imageview.setRotation(5);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String img_path = extras.getString("img_path");

    File image_file = new File(img_path);
    try {
        Bitmap captured_image = applyOrientation(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path),resolveBitmapOrientation(image_file));
        imageview.setImageBitmap(captured_image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the code on where I rotate my image maybe someone can help fix it from here too so here it is:

```
private int resolveBitmapOrientation(File bitmapFile) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    exif = new ExifInterface(bitmapFile.getAbsolutePath());

    return exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
}

private Bitmap applyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {
    int rotate = 0;
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.postRotate(rotate);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}
```

Comment: Possible dup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378573/bitmap-not-drawn-anti-aliased

Comment: already seen that post sir and it's linked on my question though the implementation he has is kind of different.